# What does "운전기사, 식모살이나 하는 주제에!!" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-meaning

I was reading a manhwwa when someone said "**운전기사, 식모살이나 하는 주제에!"** angrily to the protagonist.

The protagonist's parents are a chauffer and a maid, so I think she is saying "The driver, the maid are dead!" I'm not sure though?

Is **식모살이나** a maid?
And is "**하는 주제에**!" meaning that they're dead?

I thought 주제에 was subject. I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, "운전기사, 식모살이나 하는 주제에" is not a full sentence. It is like saying "When you're ..." or "With ..." without giving the main clause.  The implication is "Why do you act like that (when you're only [something bad])?".

식모 is a very disparaging word for the old style live-in maid with very low pay (the word is rarely if ever used anymore because it sounds offensive). 식모살이 means living (살이) as such a maid and 식모살이를 하다 is making a living doing that menial job.

주제 here is not related to "subject" and means a shameful state of being poor, dastardly, etc.  It is a disparaging expression (with a varying degree) mostly used in phrases like NOUN-인 주제에 (when you're only NOUN, where NOUN is a despised thing) or VERB-는 주제에 to suggest the person is no more than being or doing such a lowly thing, a little like "Look at you/them, you're/they're (doing) such a despisable thing". It is used when such a person expects too much for themselves or acts too out of line with their situation.

Example: 돈도 없는 주제에 고급 레스토랑만 찾는다 = He is penniless but he's still keen on going to high class restaurants.

Answer (score 1):

It roughly translates into **How dare you, you lowly driver and maid!**

That's what the syntax 감히 누구 주제에 or 감히 뭘하는 주제에 stands for, **how dare you, you (what)**.

> (1) 감히 천한놈 주제에 나한테 반말이냐! How dare you speak to me without honorifics, you low class scum!

> (2) 감히 똥간이나 치우는 주제에 나한테 반말이냐! How dare you speak to me without honorifics, you sewer cleaner!